# validate always return true even though email format is incorrect

Tags: swift

```
  func createUser(_ email: String, _ password: String) -> Bool
    {

        var validate = true 

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
        {
            (authResult, error) in

            if error != nil
            {
                validate = false
            }
        }

        return validate

    }
```

```
//validate email and register using registercontroller
        let canRegister = RC.createUser(email!, password!)

        var message = ""

        if canRegister
        {
            message = "Welcome \(name)"

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Register Success", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Back", style: .default, handler:
            {   Void in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            }))
            self.present(alert,animated:true, completion:nil)
            print(String(canRegister))
            return
        }

        else
        {
            lblErrorText.text = "Invalid email format or email already existed"
            print(String(canRegister))
            return
        }
```

I'm doing a simple firebase register process, however even though the email format is incorrect, validate will always return as true

[image: validate return true although email format is incorrect]

though it will not register into firebase. I want it to return false if error exists.

Comment: I assume `createUser` is an asynchronous method so `createUser` will return (true) before it has received the result from the call and done the actual validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create user is an asynchnous method

```
func createUser(_ email: String, _ password: String,completion:@escaping(Bool -> ())) { 

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
    {
        (authResult, error) in

         completion(error == nil)

    } 

}
```

then

```
RC.createUser(email!, password!) { canRegister in 

    if canRegister
    {
        message = "Welcome \(name)"

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Register Success", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Back", style: .default, handler:
        {   Void in
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))
        self.present(alert,animated:true, completion:nil)
        print(String(canRegister))
        return
    }

    else
    {
        lblErrorText.text = "Invalid email format or email already existed"
        print(String(canRegister))
        return
    }
 }
```